# IOS: check a plist file

Tags: xcode, ios, plist, nsbundle

I have this code: for the simulator to write a NSmutableArray in a plist

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Array" ofType:@"plist"];

if([Array writeToFile:path atomically: YES]){
    NSLog(@"write succesful");}
else {
    NSLog(@"write failed");
}
```

but how I can check if really the file plist is empty?

Comment: do you have problems writing the file? or do you want to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the file.

```
[[NSFileManger defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:plistData withAttributes:attributesDictionary];
```

Check the file for the array.

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
if ([infoDictionary count] == expectedIntegerValue) {
  NSLog(@"Success");
  if ([infoDictionary objectForKey:@"ARRAY_KEY"]) {
    NSLog(@"Found the array!");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"No Array Found.");
  }
} else {
  NSLog(@"Fail");
}
```

if you just want to know if there are any keys [infoDictionary count] > 0.

Comment: I want to know exactly how I can write an array in a plist file and check if inside this file there is the array, but NOT for the simulator.

Comment: oops shoot, forgot the code to write to a file not in the main bundle. Just a minute.

Comment: it' not clare...Can you write all that I need?

Answer (score 0):

Although this code works in the iOS Simulator, you will not be able to write into your app bundle on iOS devices.

Comment: You would probably want to write to the documents folder: `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains: NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]`